# What is VHTML? How it works? Where can I find information about it?

Tags: html, smalltalk

The code below continues many lines until it ends with a expected  /veotherwise /vechoose. I started working on a development firm a little ago where they use this html version called vhtml.  I have search the web but it brings different definitions for vhtml.  I have seen some posts in Joomla about vhtml but they don't look like the code below.  I was expecting to get a pointer on how to understand the language.

It looks very similar to normal html with even very similar commands, or maybe smalltalk.  But I just can decipher it.  Any help will be appreciated.  Please post comments if you want more information.

```
<vechoose>
  <vewhen criteria='isPortalEdit'>
    widget: practices-landing-page
  </vewhen>
  <veotherwise>
    <veinclude src='private/webportal/webtemplate-content.vhtml'>
      <vesection name='content-body'>

        <% // Determine portlet visibility %>
        <vecalc expression='isEmpty = false' output='none' />

        <vechoose>
          <vewhen criteria='isEmpty'>
            <veif criteria='portlet.ifEmptyDo == "Hide"'>
              <script>getTag( 'portlet_<%=portlet.order%>' ).style.display = "none";</script>
            </veif>
            <veif criteria='portlet.ifEmptyDo == "Show Message"'>
              <%#portlet.ifEmptyMessage%>
            </veif>
          </vewhen>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an internal language between to bring server side aspect to a display on the browser.  I have been unable to find documentation on this language, and I don't think Vitrage explains it.  The server uses coyote as web browser, tomcat as a servlet handler and java as the backend.

Any new information please post.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find this: http://vitrage.sibweb.ru/english/  Looks like it could be an Apache Module called VITRAGE. Not much available in English however so am really unsure if it's a match.

On reading the code sample you posted, it looks like a XML styled procedural language. Are you sure it's available elsewhere or perhaps something that was developed internally?

Comment: It could very well be an internal Language build for our application.   But why do this instead of using any other known languange?  I guess that will be another question.  thanks Carl.

Comment: No problems Geo. There are some companies that prefer to build their own languages. FogCreek Software being one of the notable ones using their own language called Wasabi.